# Declaration of dummy argument explicit shape arrays in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran

I thought that the specification of an explicit shape dummy argument array in a subroutine can involve any integer variables, including other dummy variables (usual cases), module variables, and local variables of the present subroutine. But it turns out that local variables (which are not dummy variables) can not be used in the specification.

An example is as follows:

```
module mp
implicit none
contains
  subroutine p(b)
    integer :: m=4, n=4 !not integer,parameter :: m=4, n=4
    integer :: b(m,n)
  end subroutine p
end module mp
```

gfortran will raise `Error: Variable 'm' cannot appear in the expression at (1)`

For this example, I can use `integer,parameter :: m=4, n=4` to avoid this, but I do not understand why the original case does not work, considering the fact that the bounds/extents of explicit shape arrays do not need to be known at compile time. A modified version of the above example works:

```
module mp
implicit none
integer :: m=4, n=4
contains
  subroutine p(b)
    integer :: b(m,n)
  end subroutine p
end module mp
```

Considering the slight difference between the two examples, I expect both of them work, but in fact the former does not. Could someone explain the reason?

Update: I found out that this is a very subtle issue because it depends on whether the subroutine is contained in a module or is standalone, it also depends on the version of gfortran. I have posted examples in the answer region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formally, there are requirements on what the bounds in such an *explicit shape* array are.  These don't simply map to "don't have to be known at compile time".

For an array explicit shape, the array bounds must be *specification expressions*.  Often, such bounds must be *constant expressions*, but this is not the case for dummy arguments.  This partly gives rise to the (erroneous) thought that they needn't be known at compile time.

However, the constraints for a specification expression must still be met.  These can be found in Fortran 2018 10.1.11.  In particular, a local variable (even a saved one) may not appear in a specification expression.

For the examples of the question, using named constants such as with

```
integer, parameter :: m=4, n=4
```

is allowed in a specification expression.  Indeed, the specification expressions `m` and `n` are even constant expressions in this case.

If we had

```
function p(b,m,n)
  integer m, n, b(m,n)
end function
```

then we have valid specification expressions for the array bounds, even though `m` and `n` are not constants.

Comment: I still can not understand why there is this constraint (local variable can not appear in a specification expression). This constraint seems to be inconsistent. From the fact that a local variable in a module can be used in a specification expression, logically we should infer that a local variable of the present subroutine can also be used in the specification expression.

Comment: Note that a module variable can't be used in a specification expression for the bounds of another module variable.  The module variable can be used in a module subpogram as a specification expression because it is explicitly allowed by the section given.  Now, whether that is intuitive or necessary...

Comment: Your first sentence seems to mix up several things. A module can never contain any array with unknown variables in its specification expressions.

Comment: That's the point of no inconsistency: we can't have local variables of a subroutine used in a specification expression in that subroutine any more than we can have a module variable used in a specification expression for another module variable .

Comment: We are talking about a dummy argument explicit shape array, which can only exist in a subroutine/function, never can appear in a module or main program, just as the same as an automatic array can never appear in a module or main program.

Comment: I insist that there is inconsistency here. A consistent way should forbid both, i.e., neither local variables of a subroutine nor variables from a module can be used in the specification expression of a dummy argument explicit array.

Comment: My testing indicates a module variable can be used in specification expression of dummy argument explicit shape arrays and automatic arrays of any subroutines (including standalone subroutines and subroutines contained in a module (no matter it is the same module or another module)).

Comment: Module variables indeed may be used in specification expressions (being use or host associated as they would be).  This is explicitly allowed under the rules given.  I can't address the motivation of the standard writers in allowing that, but it's clearly intentional (whether one views it as consistent or not).

Answer (score 2):

The right workaround is to put the procedure body in a BLOCK construct:

```
module mp3
contains
  subroutine p(b)
    implicit none
    integer :: m=4, n=4 
BLOCK
    integer :: b(m,n)
END BLOCK
 end subroutine p
end module mp3
```

The fact that it works in gfortran-8 as a standalone subroutine should be reported on bugzilla. You've got a nice minimal example there.

**EDIT**: I hadn't noticed that `b` was a dummy argument. I was thinking more in terms of something like

```
module mp3
contains
  subroutine p(x)
    implicit none
    real x
    integer :: m=4, n=4 
BLOCK
    integer :: b(m,n)
END BLOCK
 end subroutine p
end module mp3
```

But as the example stands the BLOCK approach just can't work. Also gfortran 8.1.0 rejects the form with the standalone subroutine:

```
  subroutine p(x)
    implicit none
    real x
    integer :: m=4, n=4 
    integer :: b(m,n)
 end subroutine p

Error: Variable 'm' cannot appear in the expression at (1)
```

(As it should)

Comment: This workaround does not work (tested by using `gfortran-8`:  `Error: Symbol ‘b’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type`). The reason why it does not work is also obvious: array `b(m,n)` is defined in a local scope and it has nothing to do with the dummy argument array `b`

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I hadn't noticed that `b`was a dummy argument.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found out that this is a very subtle issue because it depends on the version of `gfortran` and also depends on whether the subroutine is contained in a module or is standalone.
Neither gfortran-4.8 or gfortran-8 can compile successfully the following code:

```
module mp3
contains
  subroutine p(b)
    implicit none
    integer :: m=4, n=4 
    integer :: b(m,n)
 end subroutine p
end module mp3
```

But if we consider a standalone subroutine as follows:

```
 subroutine p(b)
    implicit none
    integer :: m=4, n=4 
    integer :: b(m,n)
 end subroutine p
```

Then `gfortran-4.8` still reject this form, but `gfortran-8` accepts this, which may be just a bug in `gfortran-8` because further testing (by user5713492) indicates that `gfortran-8.1.0` also rejects this form.

In summary, local variables of a subroutine are not allowed in the specification expression of dummy argument arrays.

Using local non-constant variables in specification expressions is not very often needed. So it is not a terrible idea to forbid this usage.